# Extracting year from dob using lubridate in r

Tags: r, tidyverse, lubridate

I have a dataset with `dob` as one of the variables, but the data stored in `dob` is not consistent. The data frame looks like this -

```
    dob         
   <chr>             
 1 06 Jan 1933    
 2 06 Jan 1933     
 3 1939    
 4 1939     
 5 Jul 1935    
 6 Jul 1935
```

I need to create a new variable `dob_Year` with the year part of the `dob`.I use the `dmy` function and `year` function from `lubridate` package, but I could not extract the year part of the `dob` for all rows. Please note that `dob` is `character` type now.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: use `str_extract(df$dob,"(?<= )\\d{4}(?= )")`

Comment: Hi @Onyambu - I tried your code, but it does not work. Can you guess, where the issue might be ?

Comment: As you are using `lubridate` could use this: `year(parse_date_time(df$dob, c("dbY", "bY", "Y")))`?

Comment: just include the anchors: `str_extract(df$dob,"(?<= |^)\\d{4}(?= |$)")` if you are sure that all the characters are date, then you could just do `str_extract(df$dob,"\\d{4}")`

Comment: @Ben Thanks. It works well. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comment, you can use `parse_date_time` function from `lubridate`. You can specify several format-orders to handle heterogeneous date-time character representations.

Example data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  dob = c("06 Jan 1933", "1939", "Jul 1935")
)
```

Using `parse_date_time` - see [here](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/parse_date_time.html) for reference and formats:

```
library(lubridate)

year(parse_date_time(df$dob, c("dbY", "bY", "Y")))
```

**Output**

```
[1] 1933 1939 1935
```